# Typescript remove union from key

Tags: typescript

## Part 1

I have the type alias

```
type Name = {First_Name: "Bob" | "Alice" | "Ash", Last_Name: "Aaron" | "Kim"};
```

I want to remove all names starting with an "A", so removing

```
{First_Name: "Alice" | "Ash", Last_Name: "Aaron"};
```

To get

```
{First_Name: "Bob", Last_Name: "Kim"};
```

without hard coding it.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcghgW2gXigbwGIEsBOBnYAfXiQC4oAiAIQHsAjCqAH0oEEAbLAYwkZYtZ4AFhQA0UADJwCxRBHIC4OGgDs+lANJYEFAL4AofewjAoXAK4EaSHORIp02fEXsLaDKOKkzXm7XsMgA)

## Part 2

Modification to part 1 question

I have the type alias

```
type Name = {First_Name: "Bob" | "Alice" | "Ash", Last_Name: "Aaron" | "Kim" | "Bob"};
```

Removing the names with an "A" is already solved. Now I also want to remove "Bob" from "Last_Name" while keeping "Bob" in "First_Name", so removing

```
{First_Name: "Alice" | "Ash", Last_Name: "Aaron" | "Bob"};
```

To get

```
{First_Name: "Bob", Last_Name: "Kim"};
```

Comment: Which values should be removed from the union ?

Comment: [Here's an example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcghgW2gXigbwGIEsBOBnYAfXiQC4oAiAIQHsAjCqAH0oEEAbLAYwkZYtZ4AFhQA0UADJwCxRBHIC4OGgDs+lANJYEFAL4AofaEhQqEAOZYVKq+YDqWYEIA8rKBAAewCCoAmeKAIcWwA+KFQAAwASNFZdGKDbXQjDY2gAUQ8udgBXXwgAEQgIMGcAFXEANTDUNH0oBqgAbQ0oKygAawgQGgAzKDKAXXJM7LyIcpbBqpD9A312CGAoLhyCGiQcEazc-KKS5xIIcTNLa1sHJ2cAclZrkJr0bHwiI4VaBihxKRk3tiVVHpDEA) how to exclude values beginning with `A`

Comment: What's the criteria for the items that should be removed? Or specifically looking for `"Bob"` and `"Kim"`?

Comment: @Teneff Thanks. There's a typo for Last_Name. It's supposed to be Kim, not Aaron. Updated [link with fixed typo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcghgW2gXigbwGIEsBOBnYAfXiQC4oAiAIQHsAjCqAH0oEEAbLAYwkZYtZ4AFhQA0UADJwCxRBHIC4OGgDs+lANJYEFAL4AofaEhQqEAOZYVKq+YDqWYEIA8rKBAAewCCoAmeKAIcWwA+KFQAAwASNFZdGKDbXQjDY2gAUQ8udgBXXwgAEQgIMGcAFXEANTDUNH0oBqgAbQ0oKygAawgQGgAzKDKAXXJM7LyIcpbBqpD9A312CGAoLhyCGiQcEazc-KKS5xIIcTNLa1sHJ2cAclZrkJr0bHwiI4VaBihxKRk3zW09IYgA)

Comment: @Behemoth Edited instructions to make it clearer. It's already solved, though.

Comment: Good that you found a solution. So you want to remove all Names starting with a `"A"`. That's what you should put in your question.

Comment: "It's already solved" means you or someone should probably post an answer.  I would do it [this way](https://tsplay.dev/wReevW).  Does @Teneff want to post an answer? Or OP?  I can do it if nobody else wants to.

Comment: @jcalz Can you post your answer?

Comment: I'll write up an answer but I'm not sure where this followup question is coming from.

Comment: @jcalz I deleted the comment and just edited the question.

Comment: It's not really fair to expand the scope of a question in response to people trying to help you with the first one.  Now the question is too broad and might be closed as needing more focus. Not sure how to proceed at this point.

Comment: I'm really in favor of closing this question. @JojoCeasar you had the chance to edit your question multiple times. Focus on one problem only at a time, don't change your requirements every once in a while and describe your issue properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Part 1

(exclude names beginning with `A`)

One way is to create a type which matches the values you want to exclude

```js
type BeginningWith<A extends string> = `${A}${string}`
```

and apply [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) on each value

```js
type ExcludeDeep<T, V> = {
    [K in keyof T]: Exclude<T[K], V>
}
```

then you'll be able to define your `customer` like this:

```js
let customer: ExcludeDeep<Name, BeginningWith<'A'>> = {
  First_Name: "Bob",
  Last_Name: "Kim"
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcghgW2gXigbygMQJYCcDOwA+vEgFxQBEAQgPYBGlUAPlQIIA22AxhE65Tb4AFpQA0UADJxCJRBAqC4uWgDt+VANLYETAL4AoA6EhRqEAObZVq6xYDq2YMIA8bKBAAewCKoAm+FCEuHYAfFCoAAYAJGhserHBdnqRRibQAKKe3BwArn4QACIQEGAuACoSAGrhqGgGUI1QANqaUNZQANYQILQAZlDlALoUWTn5EBWtQ9WhBoYGHBDAUNy5hLRIuKPZeQXFpS6kEBLmVjZ2js4uAORsN6G16A1NOATEx4p0jGIvjQD0-ygAAFgPgALReSDcYCQ3AqXBQNjKNTtQKqWgrOBQABucC4flx+NyED+UhkH3kimRKnU8yMQA)

### Part 2

You can create a type of an object with `Last_Name` based on `Name` where all values beginning with `A` or `Bob` are excluded

```js
ExcludeDeep<Pick<Name, "Last_Name">, BeginningWith<'A'> | 'Bob'>
```

and with that create a union with the previous type e.g.

```js
type Customer = ExcludeDeep<Name, BeginningWith<'A'>> & ExcludeDeep<Pick<Name, "Last_Name">, BeginningWith<'A'> | 'Bob'>
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=1#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)